# Convert nested array to single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

Can anybody please help me generate a new array from an existing array. Here's my array (sample)

```
[
 1,
 2,
 [3,4],
 9
 [5,6],
 [7,8]
]
```

And here's what i want to achieve

```
[
 [1,2,3,9,5,7],
 [1,2,4,9,5,7],
 [1,2,3,9,6,7],
 [1,2,4,9,6,7],
 [1,2,3,9,5,8],
 [1,2,4,9,5,8],
 [1,2,3,9,6,8],
 [1,2,4,9,6,8]
]
```

Thanks

Edit
Because I want to make a proper combination of the nested array. I dont think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript) will help.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký I am still trying to figure out a proper way to do this. I just need a head start. thanks

Comment: @user184994 nah I looked at that answer. i don't think concat would work here.

Comment: @user184994 it is not a simple flattening

Comment: @charlietfl exactly.

Comment: How dynamic is this array? Will multiples always be in same locations for example?

Comment: @charlietfl It is very dynamic. The length of the nested array can be different and at different positions.

Comment: @WdyDev could you please explain the result? What criteria is there to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) so you could create recursive function for that.

```js
var data = [ 1, 2, [3,4], 9, [5,6], [7,8] ];

function convert(data, n = 0, c = [], r = []) {
  if(n == data.length) return r.push(c.slice());
  let el = Array.isArray(data[n]) ? data[n] : [data[n]]
  for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    c[n] = el[i];
    convert(data, n + 1, c, r);
  }
  return r;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(convert(data)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that creates first element from first elements in data, then maps new arrays from that base in  `reduce()`

```js
var data = [1, 2, [3, 4], 9, [5, 6],  [7, 8]];

const base = data.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e[0] : e);
const res = data.reduce((a, el, dIdx) => {
  if (Array.isArray(el)) {
    let newArrs = el.slice(1).map(nVal => {
      return [...a.map(arr => arr.map((val, i) => i === dIdx ? nVal : val))];
    })
    return a.concat(...newArrs)
  }
  return a;
}, [base]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```